# change name of tab title place holder with current tab

Tags: javascript

I've tried a few things , but not versed enough in coding to get it done myself obviously

I setup a jsfiddle here - https://jsfiddle.net/7ojfmxn2/17/

I have a show tabs function to display tab content below , i have a header text for the tabs and i'd like to change that text to the name of the current tab each time one is clicked "League Tabs" i'd like renamed to Tab 0 , Tab 1 , Tab 2 ect , whenever one is selected, any help ?

```
function show_tab(tab_id) {
  var done = false;
  var counter = 0;
  while (!done) {
    var this_tab_content = document.getElementById("tabcontent" + counter);
    var this_tab = document.getElementById("tab" + counter);
    if (!this_tab_content) {
      done = true;
    } else {
      if (counter == tab_id) {
        this_tab_content.style.display = '';
        this_tab.className = "currenttab";
      } else {
        this_tab_content.style.display = 'none';
        this_tab.className = "";
      }
    }
    counter++;
  }
  location.hash = tab_id;
}

if (location.hash) {
  show_tab(location.hash.substr(1));
} else {
  show_tab(0);
}
```

Comment: The name of the tab comes from the `title` tag in the HTML, so you would have to change that first, but I'm uncertain if the browser would automatically change it in the tab or if you would have to push some sort of refresh on it.

Comment: i don't care if the title tab name reverts on page refresh , i'm only concerned about change the title tab on click event of any of the tabs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure it is what you're asking for, but if you want substitute "League Tabs" with the Tab name, you could do as follows

1- give an ID to the span where the tab header is stored , for example id=tabheader

2- in the part of code where you set the visible tab, also set the content of that span (the element with id=tabheader)

Here's the code

HTML

```
...
<div class="myfantasyleague_tabmenu"><span id="tabheader">LEAGUE TABS</span>
....
```

JS

```
....
 if (counter == tab_id) {
        this_tab_content.style.display = '';
        this_tab.className = "currenttab";
        var tabheader = document.getElementById("tabheader");
        tabheader.innerHTML="tab " + counter;
      }
...
```

See updated fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/7ojfmxn2/30/

EDIT

If you want the title LEAGUE TABS be displaied at the beginning, you've to comment your init code in a way no tab is selected.

```
/*
if (location.hash) {
  show_tab(location.hash.substr(1));
} else {
  show_tab(0);
}
*/
```

EDIT 2
To avoid showing all tabs you can use

```
         show_tab(-1);
```

instead of

```
        show_tab(0);
```

see fiddle [https://jsfiddle.net/7ojfmxn2/50/](https://jsfiddle.net/7ojfmxn2/47/)

EDIT 3

In the case you want to see the 'main' tab name on page load, having anyway the tab 0 loaded, you may

1- change the show_tab, adding an input param. This boolean param determines what to show (main tab name or displaied tab name ), as follows

```
 function show_tab(tab_id, show_main_tab_name) {
   .....
   //here is where the tab title is displaied 
   var tabheader = document.getElementById("tabheader");
    if(show_main_tab_name){
        tabheader.innerHTML="LEAGUE TABS";
    }
    else {
       tabheader.innerHTML="tab " + counter;
    }
    ....
```

2- call on init the show tab with the param set to true
 (I put your original function)

```
if (location.hash) {
  show_tab(location.hash.substr(1));
} else {
  show_tab(0,true);
}
```

See my new fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/7ojfmxn2/55/

Comment: that is almost perfect , only thing is , i wanted the title League Tabs , to display until you click on any of the tabs , at which point the title tab name would change , is that possible ?

Comment: only if no tab is selected. Instead, in your example there's always a tab selected. I'll see in a few

Comment: if you comment out the init code , then all tab content shows up on page load https://jsfiddle.net/7ojfmxn2/45/  , any other idea ?

Comment: You're right, maybe you can substitute the code with show_tab(-1); See the fiddle in my answer

Comment: ah this stinks :(  now no tab content displays on page load , i'd like to always have tab 0 load by default , wonder if the changing on name needs to be done only onclick event ?

Comment: see my answer for a solution to this

Answer (score 1):

Add an `id` to your HTML's `<title>` tag, like so:

```
<title id="myTitle"></title>
```

Using jQuery you could just do this:

```
$('#myTitle').html(this_tab.className);
```

With JavaScript it would be

```
document.getElementById("myTitle").innerText = this_tab.className;
```

Comment: You're not putting HTML inside the title tag, so it would be `innerText`, not `innerHTML`. Also, adding an ID is unnecessary because there is only ever one `title` tag in the document.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set an `id` on the title of the element that contains the tabs, so you can later select it and change it's content.

Then you can pass a 2nd parameter to your `show_tab` function which would be the tab title you want to display.

Here's the updated code (**I had to delete the CSS to be able to post it here due to post size limits**)

Here's the working Fiddle with all the CSS https://jsfiddle.net/7ojfmxn2/39/

```js
function show_tab(tab_id, tab_title) {
  var done = false;
  var counter = 0;
  while (!done) {
    var this_tab_content = document.getElementById("tabcontent" + counter);
    var this_tab = document.getElementById("tab" + counter);
    if (!this_tab_content) {
      done = true;
    } else {
      if (counter == tab_id) {
        this_tab_content.style.display = '';
        this_tab.className = "currenttab";
      } else {
        this_tab_content.style.display = 'none';
        this_tab.className = "";
      }
    }
    counter++;
  }
  location.hash = tab_id;
  document.getElementById('tab_title').innerHTML = tab_title || 'LEAGUE TABS';
}

if (location.hash) {
  show_tab(location.hash.substr(1));
} else {
  show_tab(0);
}
```

```html
<div id="contentframe">
    <div id="withmenus">

      <div class="myfantasyleague_tabmenu"><span id="tab_title">LEAGUE TABS</span>
        <input id="sub100" type="checkbox">
        <label for="sub100"><span></span></label>
        <ul id="homepagetabs">
          <li id="tab0" onclick="javascript:show_tab('0', 'Tab 0');"><a class="no-sub">Tab 0<input id="sub100" type="checkbox"><label for="sub100"></label></a></li>
          <li id="tab1" onclick="javascript:show_tab('1', 'Tab 1');"><a class="no-sub">Tab 1<input id="sub100" type="checkbox"><label for="sub100"></label></a></li>
          <li id="tab2" onclick="javascript:show_tab('2', 'Tab 2');"><a class="no-sub">Tab 2<input id="sub100" type="checkbox"><label for="sub100"></label></a></li>
          <li id="tab3" onclick="javascript:show_tab('3', 'Tab 3');"><a class="no-sub">Tab 3<input id="sub100" type="checkbox"><label for="sub100"></label></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div id="tabcontent0" class="homepagetabcontent">
        <div class="mobile-wrap">
          <table align="center" cellspacing="1" class="homepagemodule report" id="brief_standings">
            <caption><span>Tab 0 CONTENT</span></caption>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td id="division00" colspan="3">
                  <h3>Division 1</h3></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th class="fname" title="Franchise Name">Franchise</th>
                <th class="h2hwlt" title="Overall Wins, Losses and Ties">W&#8209;L&#8209;T</th>
                <th class="pf" title="Points For (Total Year-to-Date Point Scored)">PF</th>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="tabcontent1" class="homepagetabcontent">
        <div class="mobile-wrap">
          <table align="center" cellspacing="1" class="homepagemodule report" id="brief_standings">
            <caption><span>Tab 1 CONTENT</span></caption>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td id="division00" colspan="3">
                  <h3>Division 1</h3></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th class="fname" title="Franchise Name">Franchise</th>
                <th class="h2hwlt" title="Overall Wins, Losses and Ties">W&#8209;L&#8209;T</th>
                <th class="pf" title="Points For (Total Year-to-Date Point Scored)">PF</th>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="tabcontent2" class="homepagetabcontent">
        <div class="mobile-wrap">
          <table align="center" cellspacing="1" class="homepagemodule report" id="brief_standings">
            <caption><span>Tab 2 CONTENT</span></caption>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td id="division00" colspan="3">
                  <h3>Division 1</h3></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th class="fname" title="Franchise Name">Franchise</th>
                <th class="h2hwlt" title="Overall Wins, Losses and Ties">W&#8209;L&#8209;T</th>
                <th class="pf" title="Points For (Total Year-to-Date Point Scored)">PF</th>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="tabcontent3" class="homepagetabcontent">
        <div class="mobile-wrap">
          <table align="center" cellspacing="1" class="homepagemodule report" id="brief_standings">
            <caption><span>Tab 3 CONTENT</span></caption>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td id="division00" colspan="3">
                  <h3>Division 1</h3></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th class="fname" title="Franchise Name">Franchise</th>
                <th class="h2hwlt" title="Overall Wins, Losses and Ties">W&#8209;L&#8209;T</th>
                <th class="pf" title="Points For (Total Year-to-Date Point Scored)">PF</th>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
```

Comment: Jorge , big thumbs up !  thank you , that is exactly what i had in mind !

Comment: i didn't realize you had to manually change the tab name , these tabs are dynamically created based on users naming of the tabs , so i'd need a var to find the text name of the tabs and then use that var to put the name in